# Updating Task in Native Mobile Applications

Tags: soql, rest-api, mobile, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am using this code to update a task through a RequestForUpdate in an Android Native App
The onSuccess method is executed but It seems the field is not updated.

Why?

```
            Map<String,Object> fields = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            String id = "00Tw000001wvUCVEA2";
            fields.put("Subject", "A Subject" );
            try {
                    RestRequest.getRequestForUpdate("30.0", "Task", id, fields);
                    TaskGridFragment.this.client.sendAsync(request, new AsyncRequestCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(RestRequest request,
                                        RestResponse response) {
                                        System.out.println("UPDATE RESP "+response);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Exception exception) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    System.out.println("UPDATE FAIL ");
                                    exception.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the actual response you're getting. Depending on the API you might find that success is being called because you're getting an HTTP 200 code (i.e. ok) but it could be the content of that response actually contains an error.

Comment: The status code is 200 how can i get the content you mentioned ?

Comment: it seems it always returns 200 regardless of the Key in the fields map! How can I use it properly?

Comment: What are you seeing in the debug output from this line: `System.out.println("UPDATE RESP "+response);` That should tell you what you need to do. 

Alternatively try and update the same field with the same user via the browser to see what might be stopping you.

Comment: I get the JSON of all the existing tasks (11) included the one I tried to update

Comment: That doesn't sound right... I'd expect you to only see the one you're updating. You're definitely checking the output of the right callback and not the callback for a different request?

Comment: Great! I missed request = thus I was executing an old request. Now the problem is even worse, I get  BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://eu3.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Task/00Tw000001wvUCVEA2 why !??

Comment: That's HTTP BAD REQUEST. You're going to have to check any error info, and make sure your request is in the right format. Workbench might be of some use to verify things are formatted correctly: https://workbench.developerforce.com/

Comment: I am using a request created through the getRequestForUpdate method! how can it be in bad format?  How can I check its format?

Comment: Without seeing what's going on anythign I do now will just be guessing. I'd check the record ID exists though as a start :)

Comment: It does exist :(